# On the Borel Class

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $T$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. We can consider the Borel class in this space, namely, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets of $T$.

The author wrote that, if $E\subseteq T$ is such that $E\cap K$ being a relatively compact Borel set for any compact set $K$, then $E$ is Borel.

I have looked for all the references regarding measure theory that I have, no such assertion is made ever.

For simplicity, let
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}=\{E: E\cap K~\text{is a relatively compact Borel set for every compact }K\},
\end{align*}
one can use the tricks in the book of Nicolae Dinculeanu, *Vector Measures*, Chapter 1, to deduce that
\begin{align*}
\text{Borel class}~\subseteq\mathcal{I},
\end{align*}
but the other direction is not clear to me.

Of course, if there is a sequence of compact sets which the union equals to $T$, then the assertion is trivial, but in this case the author did not assume that.

**EDIT:**

I just figured out that this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569356/relation-between-two-different-definitions-for-a-borel-sigma-algebra-on-a-loc) somehow addresses the same issue. Allow me to elaborate a little bit.

As the OP stated in the post, the author (Nicolae Dinculeanu) has defined something like that:

In the Chapter 3 of the book, for any compact set $K$, $\mathcal{B}_{K}$ is defined to be the *tribe* generated by all the compact subsets of $K$. Since $K$ is itself compact and $T$ is Hausdorff, it is the same to say that $\mathcal{B}_{K}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the closed subsets of $K$, and it is exactly the Borel class of $K$.

The author then defined $\mathcal{B}$ the *semi-tribe* generated by the compact sets of $T$, and he managed to show that
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{B}=\bigcup_{K}\mathcal{B}_{K}.
\end{align*}
He then defined
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{C}=\{E: A\cap E\in\mathcal{B},~A\in\mathcal{B}\},
\end{align*}
and managed to show that
\begin{align*}
E\in\mathcal{C}~~~~\text{if and only if}~~~~K\cap E\in\mathcal{B}~\text{for every compact set}~K,
\end{align*}
and $\mathcal{C}$ is a *tribe* which containing $\mathcal{B}$.

Note that $K\cap E\in\mathcal{B}$ if and only if $K\cap E\in\mathcal{B}_{F}$ for some compact set $F$, this holds if and only if $K\cap E$ is a relatively compact Borel subset of $F$, so $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{I}$.

The answer given by @DanielWainfleet in that post is too difficult for me due to the lacking of the knowledge of Borel hierachy and limit ordinal all that, so I am looking for a simpler example that $I\nsubseteq~\text{Borel class}$.

Comment: Your second paragraph starts: "The author wrote that"...Who is this author and what are you quoting from?

Comment: Same author, Nicolae Dinculeanu, but that line is from his another book, *Integration on Locally Compact Spaces*, I didn't read Chapter 3 from his first book *Vector Measures*, so I didn't know that the author addressed the Borel issue like what I am concerned.